# chrome extension - select facebook comment field using content script

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to select facebook comment form that is under each post using a content script of a chrome extension. Unfortunately after inspecting the DOM I've noticed that they use a lot of divs and I'm unable to find the correct one beacuse of the class names. I think they are using react or angular to generate the dom. Is there any way to achive my scope?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. They have an API if you want to programmatically interact with them

Comment: @WizKid I don't need to interact with their API, I need to analyze a comment before it's posted using tensorflow. Anyway I've already scraped fb contents in past, the trick is to find the DOM elements that hold the interested content.

Comment: Good luck then. The DOM will change all the time. So be aware that you will have to update your extension all the time.

Comment: I've solved using `contextMenu` api. And for the DOM ot will not change certain elements ;)